# Grepl for 2 words/phrases in proximity in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, escaping, grepl

I'm trying to create a filter for large dataframe. I'm trying to use grepl to search for a series of text within a specific column. I've done this for single words/combinations, but now I want to search for two words in close proximity (ie the word tumo(u)r within 3 words of the word colon).

I've checked my regular expression on https://www.regextester.com/109207 and my search works there, but it doesn't work within R.

The error I get is
Error: '\W' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\btumor|tumour)\W"

Example below - trying to search for tumo(u)r within 3 words of cancer.

Can anyone help?

```
library(tibble)
example.df <- tibble(number = 1:4, AB = c('tumor of the colon is a very hard disease to cure', 'breast cancer is also known as a neoplasia of the breast', 'tumour of the colon is bad', 'colon cancer is also bad'))

filtered.df <- example.df %>% 
    filter(grepl(("\btumor|tumour)\W|\w+(\w+\W+){0,3}colon\b"), AB, ignore.case=T)
```

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez So the term for a parenthesis in a delimited capture class expression is "anchor"? I did not know that. Is there a canonical place to refer people to for correct terminology to use in describng regex syntax?

Comment: not sure if it's the right terminology, but on [www.regextester.com](https://www.regextester.com/) it tells you the terminology when you hover over a part of the code -- they call the "\b" (or "\\b") the "word boundary"

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez When I go to regex tutorials, the term ‘anchors’ is used only to refer to “$” and “^”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R uses backslashes as escapes and the regex engine does,too. Need to double your backslashes. This is explained in multiple prior questions on StackOverflow as well as in the help page brought up at `?regex`. You should try to use the escaped operators in a more simple set of tests before attempting complex operations. And you should pay better attention to the proper placement of parentheses and quotes in the pattern argument.

```
filtered.df <- example.df %>% 

   #filter(grepl(("\btumor|tumour)\W|\w+(\w+\W+){0,3}colon\b"), AB, 

# errors here ....^.^..............^..^...^..^.............^.^

    filter(grepl( "(\\btumor|tumour)\\W|\\w+(\\w+\\W+){0,3}colon\\b", AB,
ignore.case=T) )

> filtered.df
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  number AB                                               
   <int> <chr>                                            
1      1 tumor of the colon is a very hard disease to cure
2      3 tumour of the colon is bad
```

Comment: much appreciated, thanks!  I was looking up `grepl` on stackoverflow and R... not `regex` - my mistake on that one, so I appreciate the suggestion (and helpful changes to my code)